# SSRS gauge label default if no value

Tags: reporting-services, gauge

I have a gauge with a label containing the value from a column in the dataset the gauge is based upon.  Sometimes there won't be a value for a particular row.  I'm passing the name of a person in from another report.  This works correctly but displays "Text" if there isn't a value for that person.  It displays the numeric value if this is.  How can I control what's displayed instead of "text" in the label?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an expression to test the value that might be coming in, and if it's missing/invalid, replace it with something else.  IsNothing(), or Len()/Length() sound like they're what you need.

Comment: Thanks Kyzen.  I did what you suggested and it worked well.  Here's the code if anyone needs it: =IIf(Fields!CompositeScore.Value <0 or Fields!CompositeScore.Value > 100,Fields!CompositeScore.Value," N/A")